# Use SHA password value for ansible_become_pass

Tags: hash, passwords, ansible

Is it possible to store the SHA value of `ansible_become_pass` in the vault, instead of the plain text version?

My main use-case is that I already have the SHA value needed to setup the `sudo` user, I want to use the same SHA value to set the `ansible_become_pass`. So far `ansible_become_pass` seems to only accept plain text passwords.

This would avoid the slight kludge of specifying the same password in two different ways in the vault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to store the SHA value of ansible_become_pass in the vault, instead of the plain text version?

No! Of course you cannot.

`ansible_become_pass` is a password which Ansible provides to the target operation system to authenticate for actions to be performed with `sudo` on behalf of another user.

You cannot login to any system by providing a password hash instead of using the password.

The whole point of using a hash (one way function) is that it cannot be used for authentication (password retrieval) even if it was compromised.

---

> [ ] avoid the slight kludge of specifying the same password in two different ways in the vault.

You can use the [`password_hash` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#hashing-filters) to get a hash of a password, you don't need to store the hashed value alongside a plain-text password.

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local
  vars:
    plain_text_password: secret
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ plain_text_password | password_hash }}"
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ plain_text_password | password_hash('sha256') }}"
```